# Can I remove event listeners with a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

In Chrome's dev tools, there's a lovely interface where you can see all the event listeners attached to a given DOM element, and remove any of them as you see fit. Here's a screenshot (arrow added for emphasis):

[image: Removing an event listener with Chrome dev tools]

I'd like to write a Chrome extension that automatically removes event listeners from any web page (I'm trying to write a Chrome extension to disable smooth scrolling on any website that tries to force it upon you -- I figure removing the 'wheel' listener from `<body>` is the most direct route to do this). Is there any JavaScript API available for accessing and modifying this list of event listeners from a Chrome extension, or is it limited to the dev tools GUI?

To be clear, I'm aware of [removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener), but that method requires that you have a reference to the original listener object -- I have no such reference, so that method won't suit my purposes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

eholder0's answer unfortunately doesn't help when the event listener is registered on `window` (like in your question) or `document`. For that, one way is that most code and libraries usually registers event listeners on the bubbling phase, by passing in false for the third `useCapture` parameter of `addEventListener` (or just not passing it in at all). Since the capturing phase happens first, you can prevent event listeners from being invoked by registering a capturing phase listener that stops further propagation.

So for your case, you can do the following in the extension's content script:

```js
document.addEventListener("wheel", event => event.stopPropagation(), true);
```

... or more explicitly:

```js
document.addEventListener("wheel", event => event.stopPropagation(), { capture: true });
```

Notice the third parameter is `true` to register a capturing phase event listener. Also notice that it does *not* call `event.preventDefault()`, so the browser's built-in scrolling function is retained.

---

An addendum based on the comments: In the case where the handler you want to suppress is on a specific element rather than `document`, you can also register the capturing handler on that element, so that events in the rest of the document are not impacted.

Comment: Oh my god this works perfectly! Dropped it into a Greasemonkey script (changing the event type from "mousedown" to "wheel"), and it worked like a charm. It's a little bit _too_ effective now (it blocks scrolling _at all_ inside the text editor on GitHub, for example), but now that I know the trick, I can fine tune it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to downvote and now I can't change it :-(

Comment: i tried to add an event listener "visibilitychange" to document, but the site i am using is still able to add it. i even tried modifying tampermonkey's "run-at" to make sure the script loaded before everything else

Comment: also, this doesn't work when the eventlistener done by the site is sourced from an external file. I can see 3 "copies" on the "visibilitychange" listener in the document, mine appears at the bottom

Comment: This script may sabotage wanted use of mouse-wheel events, such as navigation from month to month in Google Calendar.

Comment: My GOD! Been searching for this for so long, that does the trick! Are you God?

Comment: Here I realise the drawback of routinely using jQuery. Its `on()` method also attaches event listeners, but lacks the option of intervening in the capturing phase.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately because of how event listeners are implemented, this isn't trivially possible. There are some libraries you can use which record calls to add event listeners, thereby giving you a reference to remove. Short of using those or rolling your own, the isn't a simple tool to remove them anonymously.

You can however do something which will effectively remove all listeners, which is to clone the element and replace it with the clone. Cloning does not preserve any listeners on the element or its children, though it does otherwise preserve all attributes. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('foo'),
clone = elem.cloneNode(true);
elem.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, elem);
```

Comment: As you say, this removes all listeners, which often is not what one wishes. Arnavion's method (checkmarked answer) is far superior.