# Vanilla JavaScript: Disabling a given preexisting key-combo in a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, return, keyboard-shortcuts

In this random [English-Wikipedia edit page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=User_talk:109.66.120.141&action=edit&section=new) one can add some content (say "test"), then saving it by the preexisting key-combo of <kbd>Alt+Shift+S</kbd>.

I desire to prevent this behavior **specifically** (without removing the save button with `document.querySelector("#wpSave").remove();`).

I tried the following code that failed:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         wiki
// @match        https://*.wikipedia.org/*
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.key == 16 && e.key == 18 && e.key == 83) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I also tried replacing `return false` with `e.preventDefault()` or `evt.stopPropagation()`, but all failed (no console errors).

What's wrong with the code?

---

<sub>**Note:** This question differs from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915887/vanilla-js-totally-disabling-a-save-functionality-in-webpages) by focusing on disabling a given preexisting key-combo functionality in general, and not on *saving functionalities* in general.</sub>

---

## Update for dotoconor

I used this in console but I still have the same problem:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
    const state = {};
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        state[e.key] = true;
    });

    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        state[e.key] = false;
    });

    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        state[e.key] = false;
        if (state["Alt"] && state["Shift"] && (state["S"] || state["s"])) {
            return e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding Browser's Keyboard Shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: [The values of `key` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values) would be good to know ... And how [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Only one key event will be present at a time, so you have to create a state machine to determine which ones are on and off.
Consider this:

```js
const state = {};
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  state[e.key] = true;
});
```

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  state[e.key] = false;
});
```

Now with this, you can check if your desired keys are all being pushed down at one time, then prevent the last keypress from trickling down the DOM.

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  state[e.key] = false;
  if (state["Alt"] && state["Shift"] && (state["S"] || state["s"])) {
    return e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: There are problems, here you here?

Comment: I've updated the question with the code I used, please review it there.