# Vanilla JavaScript: Disable all key combos whatsoever in an entire website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, keyboard

Sometimes when you use websites, they contain one or more keyboard combos or ("keyboard shortcuts") like <kbd>Alt+Shift+S</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL+Shift+D</kbd> that are, by some view, unique to that website (or one or more webpages in that website).

A good broad example would be the different key combos you get when you are in the [**edit-page** of a random user-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=User_talk:109.66.120.141&action=edit&section=new) in Wikipedia (standing with the mouse on an option will usually display the link's description describing its key combo).

### Possible problem

Sometimes a website's set of key combos can clash with these of a given operating system (or even cause editorial mistakes if a combo was used in a rare mistake).

### My question

Is there a "violent" (and vanillic) JavaScript way to disable **all preexisting keycombos whatsoever** in an entire website? Not just one or two preexisting (specific) key combos but all of them, in one go?

Maybe some kind of `for` loop that will do that?

I could run this code in some browser script-executor like Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey.

### Why I ask this question:

I ask this question after yet finding "satisfying" answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915887/vanilla-js-totally-disabling-a-save-functionality-in-webpages) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52924807/vanilla-javascript-disabling-a-given-preexisting-key-combo-in-a-webpage) that I personally asked, and contains all sorts of codes I've tried so far.

### Important note:

Generally I don't think anyone should do this (and surly not forcing it on others) as it decreases [Web Accessibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accessibility) of web applications in general; the problem I described is rare and deals with a personal issue I have.

Comment: I did the same. It's not often you see a really well written question, definitely deserve that upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd try blocking the event listeners by [the method described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46986927/9115285).

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",  function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); }, true);
window.addEventListener("keyup",    function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); }, true);
window.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); }, true);
```

This would stop all listeners watching for any key presses. If that's too broad, you could add some logic to only stopPropagation if modifier keys are being held, e.g.

```
if (e.ctrlKey) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

**Edit:**

The above code works on the page I used for testing but not on your wikipedia talk page because the wiki page isn't actually using event listeners, but rather the [accesskey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey) attribute. In this case, removing the attribute will remove the keyboard shortcut:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[accesskey]").forEach(function(el) {
  el.removeAttribute('accesskey');
});
```

Comment: wow ! I never heard of this concept before in JavaScript. I assume it has to do with *Web Accessibility* and might be a new concept. I'll try to read on it. I thank you dearly for your help dear Dan !!!